# How do I install the FormBuilder 2 plugin in my local Craft project?

Tags: plugins, plugin-formbuilder2

I tried cloning https://github.com/roundhouse/FormBuilder-2-Craft-CMS to my plugins folder of my local Craft project and opened the plugins module from admin settings but the formbuilder2 plugin did not show in the list. Can you please help me if somebody has used this plugin for their Craft CMS project? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I rolled old-school and just downloaded the zip file to my local machine.
When I did that & unzipped the directory the folder is called `FormBuilder-2-Craft-CMS-master`

You will want to rename that to `formbuilder2`, copy/paste that folder to `/craft/plugins/` and then it should show up in your list of plugins when you navigate to `settings->plugins`.

Hope this helps!